# Get result in upper case

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
first name       Middle Name     Last Name      UperCase
martin           Bell            MARK            N
JACK             IAN             CHAPPEL         Y
PHILIP           JIMMY           DAVID           Y
```

```
Select  CId,
    Case when CHARINDEX('N',concat(FirstName, MiddleName, LastName)) > 0 Then 'N' else 'Y' End as UperCase
From 
(
    select       
        CASE WHEN FirstName= UPPER(FirstName) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS FirstName,  
        CASE WHEN MiddleName = UPPER(MiddleName) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS MiddleName,      
        CASE WHEN LastName = UPPER(LastName) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS LastName,
    From table
)
Where A = @AsAtDate
```

I am getting syntax error in query please help me.

> Error is Incorrect syntax error near ')'

I am trying to get result in upper case column (either Y or N)

Comment: You're missing a table alias after the last bracket. And `A` is not defined at all.

Comment: also your subquery is not returning any column named `A` nor `CId`. also not sure why you needed subquery at all ,

Comment: Thank you Dale and eshirvana. i did correction and take it out from subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give alias name, and CId is not defined anywhere inside the subquery, and what is A?

```
Select  CId,
    Case when CHARINDEX('N',concat(FirstName, MiddleName, LastName)) > 0 Then 'N' else 'Y' End as UperCase
From 
(
    select CId,
        CASE WHEN FirstName= UPPER(FirstName) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS FirstName,  
        CASE WHEN MiddleName = UPPER(MiddleName) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS MiddleName,      
        CASE WHEN LastName = UPPER(LastName) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS LastName,
    From table
) As tbl
Where A = @AsAtDate
```